# Sending SMTP email via Django in production environment

Tags: django

I am using Django-Registration for my website on a linode ubuntu
virtual.  I get connection problem sending activation email when users
sign up.

Here is my settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I've tested locally and it works.  I tested interactively via python
manage.py shell on the host and it works when I logged in as root.  I
think there is a problem with permission since Apache is running under
www-data.  Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:
Someone on Linode IRC suggests that I install ssmtp package...I followed the instruction found here http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/10/21/sending-email-from-your-system-with-ssmtp/ and reboot the server...everything works great now.

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting a traceback or any error messages ?  Or is it failing silently ?

Comment: It's just sitting spinning for a while and failed silently.

Comment: Testing it interactively, does it work as www-data? Use su to become that user and try it.

Comment: I used sudo -u www-data python manage.py shell and it works.  maybe Apache is running under another user?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

EMAIL_USE_TLS = 1

rather than EMAIL_USE_TLS = True. That's my guess. If that doesn't work, try

EMAIL_DEBUG = False

although honestly I'm not sure what that one does.